# A function that is computable but not weakly time constructible

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity, turing-machines

I know that f(n) = n is a computable, weakly time constructible function but NOT a time constructible function. 
But I can't think of any computable function that is not weakly time constructible. 
Can anybody help with it?

> A function $T: \mathbb N  \rightarrow \mathbb N$ is *weakly time
>   constructible* if $T(n) \geq n$    and there is a $TM$  $M$ that computes
>   the function $x \mapsto \llcorner T(\vert x\vert) \lrcorner$ in time $O(T(n))$. 
>   ( $\llcorner T(\vert x\vert) \lrcorner$ denotes the binary representation of
>   the number $T(\vert x\vert)$.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I've updated the question with the definition.